# How can I delete NA´s within data downloaded daily from Yahoo Finance with the use of getsymbols function?

Tags: r, finance, yahoo, quantmod

```
Underlyings <- c ("AMZN", "ALV.DE", "BMW.DE")
getsymbols(Underlyings, from = "", to = "")
```

now an if or for loop for eliminating the existing NA's?

Comment: Usually calling `na.omit()` on a dataframe will remove all rows with missing values. However, all of the symbols you give in your example return complete data, so it's hard to test. I ran `getSymbols(Underlyings)`, and all three datasets were complete.

Comment: Stack Overflow requires that posts are in English. Can you please translate the body of your question into English. Thanks.

Comment: If you for example run SU.PA or SAF.PA you get data with missing values shown as NA´s. I tried the function na.omit(getSymbols(Underlyings, from = "", to = "") but there are still the NA´s contained. I thouhgt about maybe using a if or which condition to solve that ? But i don´t know how to write this in this case

Comment: the body just asked if I might use which or if condition for solving the problem, I am sorry I did not translate it

Comment: basically my problem is to get this done automatically, if I use the na.omit function for the single dowloaded data containing NA, it works, but I need a code running it automatically without the need of figuring out which data contains NA and then delete each one by using na.omit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use `lapply` and use that to call `getSymbols` with `na.omit` around it. Now when you call `getSymbols` the object will be placed directly into your environment and the na.omit can't find anything to do it's work, but you do not get a warning / error. If you use `auto.assign = FALSE` when using `getSymbols` you can assign the values yourself and the returning result from `getSymbols` can be passed on to `na.omit`. You will still get the warning that SAF.PA has empty values but in the list the values will have been removed.

**EDIT based on github script**

One of the stocks (EI.PA) in the stock list gives an error that it can not be downloaded. I added `try` around the function to catch this so it continues with the next stock.

```
library(quantmod)
underlyings <- c("^STOXX50E", "ALV.DE", "G.MI", "BMW.DE", "SU.PA", "ENI.MI", "IBE.MC", "ORA.PA", "DBK.DE",
             "BAYN.DE", "ENEL.MI", "AI.PA", "DTE.DE", "BN.PA", "SAF.PA", "BBVA.MC","PHIA.AS", 
             "OR.PA", "ASML.AS", "DPW.DE", "AIR.PA", "BNP.PA", "INGA.AS", "ENGI.PA", "ABI.BR", 
             "EI.PA", "SAN.PA", "CA.PA", "ITX.MC", "MC.PA", "FRE.DE")

my_data <- lapply(underlyings, function(x) try(na.omit(getSymbols(x, from="2016-01-01", to="2019-01-08", auto.assign = FALSE))))
names(my_data) <- underlyings

sapply(my_data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

Warning: EI.PA download failed; trying again.
Error : EI.PA download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 404.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: ^STOXX50E contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 
2: SU.PA contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 
3: SAF.PA contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 
4: ASML.AS contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 
Warning message:
SAN.PA contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them. 

# show number of empty values
sapply(my_data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

sapply(my_data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
^STOXX50E    ALV.DE      G.MI    BMW.DE     SU.PA    ENI.MI    IBE.MC    ORA.PA    DBK.DE   BAYN.DE   ENEL.MI     AI.PA    DTE.DE 
        0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0 
    BN.PA    SAF.PA   BBVA.MC   PHIA.AS     OR.PA   ASML.AS    DPW.DE    AIR.PA    BNP.PA   INGA.AS   ENGI.PA    ABI.BR     EI.PA 
        0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0 
   SAN.PA     CA.PA    ITX.MC     MC.PA    FRE.DE 
        0         0         0         0         0
```

To remove the errors from the list:

```
my_data[which(sapply(my_data, function(x) inherits(x, "try-error")) == TRUE)] <- NULL

# to create one big xts object:
my_big_xts <- Reduce(cbind, my_data)
```

But if you want to have multiple ticker symbols in a tidy data.frame you might want to look into the tidyquant package.

Comment: Thx a lot Phiver! But If I run this code the stock data is not downloaded in my environment, is it working at Yours ?

Comment: the stock data is not in the global environment, but everything is in the list object my_data. From there you can use lapply (or map) with other functions to do whatever you want.

Comment: If i run the first code you provided and then the second one called names (my_data) <- Underlyings , the system always says object my_data not found

Comment: and it always tells me to use auto.assign = TRUE

Comment: Have you restarted your R session? I ran this code in multiple fresh sessions and everything works fine. The message about `‘getSymbols’ currently uses auto.assign=TRUE by default, but will use auto.assign=FALSE in 0.5-0` you can ignore. It is always better to use `auto.assign = FALSE` so you can control what is happening.

Comment: yeah i dont know why it is not working...i restarted it as well

Comment: Is it possible that i send you my script ?

Comment: Sure. Add it on github somewhere and post the link and I'll have a look.

Comment: oh is there another possibility ? i dont have Github

Comment: a share via google drive or any other file sharing service also works.

Comment: i created GitHub

Comment: you fin your suggestion under 2.6

Comment: @SebastianMayer, changed code in answer to reflect 2.6